# How to get text from list items with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

```
<div class="carstd">
  <ul>
    <li class="cars">"Car 1"</li>
    <li class="cars">"Car 2"</li>
    <li class="cars">"Car 3"</li>
    <li class="cars">"Car 4"</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want  strip the text from each list item with mechanize and print it out. I've tried 
`puts page.at('.cars').text.strip` but it only gets the first item. I've also tried

```
page.links.each do |x|
  puts x.at('.cars').text.strip

end
```

But I get an error `undefined method 'at' for #<Mechanize::Page::Link:0x007fe7ea847810>`.

Comment: @pguardiario of course, my bad. Source code in question has been edited non-trivially since I commented too, now my selector doesn't make sense. I'll delete in a few.

Answer (score 1):

There's no links there. Links are `a` elements that get converted into special Mechanize objects.
You want something like:

```
page.search('li.cars').text # the text of all the li's mashed together as a string
```

or

```
page.search('li.cars').map{|x| x.text} # the text of each `li` as an array of strings
```